# How can i find the coordination number with voro++?

Tags: software, simulation, computational-geometry

Could anybody please help with voro++ cause i am new to this software?My problem is how can i find the coordination  number of an atom ,cause i checked it for a bcc lattice and it gave me 24 for all atoms which is correct cause the wigner-seitz polyhedron of bcc is a truncated octahedron with indeed 24 vertices. But what if i don't know the initial lattice and i want the coordination number for example for bcc is 8?Does anynody knows the option to do this???

Thanks in advance

Comment: Although this question is on-topic for scicomp.stackexchange.com, it's very specific to a particular software package that most users on this site won't be familiar with- you're more likely to get an answer by contacting the author of voro++.

Comment: Note that voro++ was developed at Lawrence Berkeley Lab- it's possible that the atuhor of the software is on furlough during the government shutdown.